# How to get beforeActionInvocation and afterActionInvocation to be called in Play module?

Tags: java, playframework

I'm working on building my first Play module. I used another module as an example and created a Plugin.java class to serve as my main interface. I can access the methods on this class easily from my tags, but it seems that the object is not going through the normal lifecycle. Specifically, `beforeActionInvocation()` and `afterActionInvocation()` are never being called.

This module is more or less a stub right now, created via "play new-module" and I've not modified any of the default files (though I have added this class and some tags).

My question is: what causes a Plugin class to go through the normal plugin lifecycle, as it seems mine is not? Is there some configuration I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

You must have a subclass of `PlayPlugin`  and a file `play.plugins`  in your classpath, where you register it with

```
1003:myPackage.MyPlugin
```

Comment: I modified play.plugins (in the default location) to reference my plugin class, but same problem. Is there an additional step to indicate the classpath so that play.plugins is found?

Comment: Is the "default" location the src-path? Then I think you must create a jar with `build-module`. I put it simple into the app-folder.

Comment: Ah yes, the default location is the src-path. I moved it to the app folder and it works. Perhaps "play new-module" should do this by default?

Comment: As far as I know it's recommended to put your Plugin into src and compile it into a jar. This has the advantage that  it wouldn't part of class-reloading. But it's obviously more complex to develop a plugin.